# combine django model with csv file and loop

Tags: python, django, csv, django-queryset

I finally manage to show csv file within html and also bind with django model but I am missing a for loop but couldn't make it work.

```
        if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['csv_file2']:
        myfile = request.FILES['csv_file2']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
        data = csv.reader(fs.open(filename, mode='r'))
        lines=[]
        instances = []
        for row in data:
            line = row[0]
            lines.append(line)
            query = line
            instances.append(FP.objects.filter(FP_Item=query))
        pair = zip(lines, instances)
        context = {'pair': pair,
                   }
        return render(request, 'check_fp.html', context)
    return render(request, 'check_fp.html', {})
```

When I use;

instances = fp.objects.filter(fp_Item=query)

It works but I get only last line information from database and missing previous lines but I need loop this "query" or is there any method like append useable with queryset filter?

Comment: You're reassigning `instances` at each `for` loop iteration, that's why you only get the last one.

Comment: This is like [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49678260/django-shows-only-last-line-while-looping), and yes, the problem is the same, you need to create `instances = []` before the loop and append each instance to it: `instances.append(fp.objects.filter(fp_Item=query)`. More importantly, you need to understand why that is necessary. The way you are doing it now, you are assigning `instances` every time the loop runs, so when the loop finishes, `instances` contains the last instance. That's why you need to store each instance in a list.

Comment: I tried append before, as you suggested and as like as previous question but not working as expected.It's just repeating as much as number of lines in csv file so retrieving nothing from the database.  Maybe it's because I am using double loop within the html file one after another like {% for line in lines %}  {% for instance in instances %}

Comment: Ok, that's a different issue. If you want to loop both at the same time you can do `pair = zip(lines, instances)` in the view, pass `pair` to the template in the `context` and then iterate `{% for line, instance in pair %}` in the template.

Comment: I modified the question according your feedbacks and tried like that now it only append "line" without problem and without multiple times but also it's not appending instances variable because I get nothing from the database.Might be because of not each line of the csv file exists in the database ? I don't need to add any import settings for zip function,right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to loop while appending the file:

```
for instance in FP.objects.filter(FP_Item=query):
 instances.append(instance)
```