# How to make statistics in django

Tags: django

I'm using django fobi to allow users to create their own forms. I would like to make some reports and stats based on those forms.

I have a working python code but I don't know how to "translate" that code in a django working template.

The data is as follows:

```
saved_data = '''
  [
       [{
           "label": "Question 1?",
           "html_name": "question_1",
           "first_name": "John",
           "last_name": "Doe",
           "email": "john@doe.com",
           "answer": "Yes"
         }, {
           "label": "Question 2?",
           "html_name": "question_2",
           "first_name": "John",
           "last_name": "Doe",
           "email": "john@doe.com",
           "answer": ["Red", "White"]
       }],
       [{
           "label": "Question 1?",
           "html_name": "question_1",
           "first_name": "Jane",
           "last_name": "Mary",
           "email": "mary@jane.com",
           "answer": "No"
         }, {
           "label": "Question 2?",
           "html_name": "question_2",
           "first_name": "Jane",
           "last_name": "Mary",
           "email": "mary@jane.com",
           "answer": ["Red", "Black"]
         }]
  ]

'''

data = json.loads(saved_data)

answer = {}

for x in data:
    for y in x:
        if type(y['answer']) is list:
            for an in y['answer']:
                answer.setdefault(y['label'], {})\
                    .setdefault('answer', []).append(an)
                answer.setdefault(y['label'], {}).setdefault('full_name', []).append(y['first_name'] + ' ' + y['last_name'])
                answer.setdefault(y['label'], {}).setdefault('email', []).append(y['email'])
        elif type(y['answer']) is str:
            answer.setdefault(y['label'], {})\
                .setdefault('answer', []).append(y['answer'])
            answer.setdefault(y['label'], {}).setdefault('full_name', []).append(y['first_name'] + ' ' + y['last_name'])
            answer.setdefault(y['label'], {}).setdefault('email', []).append(y['email'])

for questions, answers in answer.items():
    print('\n', questions)
    counting = Counter(answers['answer'])
    for key, value in counting.items():
        print(key, value)
        for answer in zip(answers['full_name'], answers['answer']):
            if key == answer[1]:
                print(answer[0])
```

How can i make this to work in a django 1.11 template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pass this into the [template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/) from a [view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/views/). For example you could use a function based view to wrap that logic and put it in views.py. You would have to add a route in urls.py and make that view return a template.

Within the template you can [for](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for) loop over the answer items and display them however you like.

Comment: I know the basics of django. From my example I can make the answer dict context and have access to it in the template. But my problem is further down the code with the Counter(). I can't import that in the template and then run the last lines of the example.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I'll try it out because a hack I can think off the top if my head is a template tag but there might be a different way to build it up

Comment: @Dragos You can do all the calculations in the view and pass just the results to the template, in whatever structure is appropriate.

Comment: @Paulo Can you please provide an example? I'm working on this problem for three weeks and I just can't see the solution. I don't know how to return context from a for loop.

Comment: @Dragos The idea is not to return context from the loop, but rather use the loop to create a data structure (e.g. a dictionary, a list) that you pass to the context. There's a simple example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775314/combine-django-model-with-csv-file-and-loop).

Comment: @PauloAlmeida Can you make an answer so I can accept it? Your hint was what I needed.

Comment: @Dragos I think you can accept Sam's answer, it has the basic insight, and the comments will be available for anyone who needs clarification (or they can be added to the answer).